# RPN with unary operators and parentheses

Tags: java, string, rpn

I've recently started familiarizing myself with some basic Java programming and am trying to complete a task set for me by a tutor. Basically, the program's meant to accept an equation that may include any of the operators `+, * and #` (we were not told exactly what # denotes, only that it is a unary operator with a higher precedence than *); and convert it into RPN to later be interpreted and transformed into basic machine code with LOAD and EXEC commands (but that's for later).

I've created the basic conversion function that seems to work well with basic equations such as A+6, but when it encounters parentheses it seems to have problems.

For example if I were to pass the following equations to it:

```
 A+6,
    A+(B*2)
    (((#9)*C)+D)+E
    (((#1)))
```

I get the following results:

```
  A6+
    A(B2)*+
    (((9)#C)*D)+E+
    (((1)))#
```

So it seems like it's only the parentheses getting in the way.
My questions are these:

- how would I best deal with the parentheses?
- Is it as simple as just removing them from the start?
- Does the unary operator have any sort of impact that would call for additional special cases?

Comment: All three questions and indeed the entire problem were solved in 1960, twice. You haven't disclosed which if any of these solutions you're using, or indeed posted any part of your solution, so your question isn't answerable in its present form.

Comment: Take a look at the Shunting-yard algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), it may provide a useful insight in to some of the issues you are facing. Although given your question, I can't really tell.

Comment: Currently I'm just removing them after the result has been provided. I'm wondering if there's any sort of special cases posed by the unary operator. I can post the code solution otherwise, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: As long as the unary operator does not have any n-ary friends with the same identifier, I don't see the problem.